# Treating two columns as one with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two paypments, each with it's own date, something like this:

```
table
______________
id
.......
payment1
payment1_date
payment2
payment2_date
```

What I need is an ordered list of payments, ignoring if it's payment1 or payment2.

payments can be both empty, only one, or both filled.

Result would look like this:

```
id        payments      date         ... 
3         (payment1)    2018-08-01
5         (payment2)    2018-08-03
4         (payment2)    2018-08-04
3         (payment2)    2018-08-07
```

Payment1 would be a payment in advance and payment2 would be the rest, but for accounting info I want to just show all payments ordered by date, being that date paymentx_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try that :

```
    select id,payment1 as payment, payment1_date as payment_date
    from table
    where payment1 is not null or payment1 <> ''
    union 
    select id,payment2 as payment, payment2_date as payment_date
    from table
    where payment2 is not null or payment2 <> ''
    order by 3
```

Comment: @monxas . . . Use `union all`!  `union` incurs the overhead of removing duplicates -- and you might not want duplicates to be removed.